# contentSize.height returns lesser height in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have a tableview inside a scrollview, and I need the tableview to display the entire content, and for which I set the height constraint of the tableview equal to its content size.

```
self.dealsTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 40;
self.dealsTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;

self.dealsTableView.delegate = self;
self.dealsTableView.dataSource = self;
[self.dealsTableView reloadData];

[self.dealsTableView layoutIfNeeded];
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
self.dealTableViewHeightConstraint.constant = self.dealsTableView.contentSize.height;
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
[self.view layoutSubviews];
[self.dealsTableView layoutIfNeeded];
```

The contentSize.height is always returned less then expected causing the view to break.
[image]

If I add a few pixels manually,

```
 self.dealTableViewHeightConstraint.constant = self.dealsTableView.contentSize.height + 50;
```

It works, but ofcourse, that cannot work in all cases. 
Any ideas?

Comment: How you are calculating self.dealsTableView.contentSize.height ??

Comment: First you have to calculate self.dealsTableView.contentSize.height then you can assign HeightConstraint's constant

Comment: I didn't get it, calculate as in? I just extracted it by self.dealstableview.contentsize!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it was a weird solution, but this is what worked.

The solution is to setup the height constraint before setting the actual content size.

```
    self.dealTableViewHeightConstraint.constant = 40 * self.business.dealArray.count;
self.dealTableViewHeightConstraint.constant = self.dealsTableView.contentSize.height;
```